# ModalView not hiding tabbar in iOS 6 and iOS 7 with storyboard segue

Tags: xcode, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

When i'm present my ViewController as Modal it not hiding tabbar on iOS 6 and iOS 7. I use storyboard segue and property hidesBottomBarWhenPushed it didnt help.
On iOS 8 works fine.